# why invoke the function from the model in the template file there is no output?

Tags: php, magento

I am  a newbie of MVC and php. now in magento app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Review.php

i add  code.

```
 public function mgtest(){
        return 'hello world!';
    }
```

in the class

```
class Mage_Review_Model_Review extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{ }
```

In magento cms page, i add code:

```
 {{block type="core/template" name="review" template="catalog/product/reviewall.phtml"}}
```

the url key is **review.html**

then add file reviewall.phtml(app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/reviewall.phtml)

then add test code in its file.

```
<?php echo $this->mgtest();?>
```

when i access url. `mysiteurl/review.html`. there is no hello world output. why? thank you. how to correct it? what all the file in the model do? if i want to invoke the function the phtml file. how do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit core to add new functionalities. Add all the additions/modifications in `app/code/local` directory.

In your existing code I see two issues:

- The block's type in CMS page should be `review/review` and not `core/template`.
- You have created function as `matest()`, but calling it as `mgtest()`

You have referenced `$this` from your reviewall.phtml, calling `matest` method which is/should residing in `Review_Block_Review` and NOT `Core_Block_Template`, so your CMS block type must be `review/review`.

I just see that you are placing `matest` method in your Model, please put it in Block, because you can't look in Model directly from template file using $this.

It's recommended to create your own custom module (in local directory) once you know how to get things done in Magento.